# Installation error with 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, asus

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows.
Booted from live USB and ran the setup but unable to proceed beyond this screen. (The setup UI crashes and disappears when clicking on Install now).

[image: The screen that appears after selecting dual boot]

How to debug this issue ?

EDIT1: Attached GParted screenshot
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted`. Also, look in your BIOS and tell me if your disk subsystem is set to RST or RAID.

Comment: @heynnema Updated the Gparted screenshot. Also, the dis subsytem is set to AHCI.

Comment: Basically you're out of disk space. The best we could do is to carve out 50G from sda4, your C: drive, and use that for Ubuntu. Best to backup some unused stuff and then delete it to make more room.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: Thank you a lot! You've made my day

Answer (score 1):

Based on [heynnema's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260220/installation-error-with-20-04/1260357#comment2130715_1260220), creating more disk space helped with continuing the installation.

> Basically you're out of disk space. The best we could do is to carve out 50G from sda4, your C: drive, and use that for Ubuntu. Best to backup some unused stuff and then delete it to make more room.

– [**heynnema**](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) [4 hours ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260220/installation-error-with-20-04/1260357#comment2130715_1260220)